# FQL query,is possible to get all events in your area?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Talking aout Facebook FQL,
is it possible to do a query like

```
SELECT name, venue, location, start_time FROM event
WHERE location ="New York"
```

to search all public events, posted on Facebook, and available in your area?

Answer (score 0):

No, since non of fields you listed are `indexable`

You can however search Graph API for public events in specified time ranges.

Which probably not suitable for your needs, since `location` field in results still not always contain reliable data, and filtering all the public events in specified range may be overkill...